# weird file, how to remove it?

Tags: server, delete

I just check my external disk on ubuntu 16.04 and I saw a weird file '`-v`'.

I am trying to delete it but can not.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root     671312164 Dec 29 16:10 -v
```

pls adive. 
thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not have a problem removing such a file using

```
rm -f ./-v
```

use the force option (`-f`) to ignore the message

```
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file './-v'? yes
```

Comment: No, you don't have to be root. You just need write permissions on the directory containing it, which *may* need root.

Comment: @muru. Thank you. Did not know that. I edited.